# back button in react native Android Webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, back-button

i have small issue with below Code in Android As the Back Button of Device Make out of my Application , i surfed in the forum but i cant find the solution for that issue .

so how Handle This handle it inside my Code

Tab1.js File is below

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { Icon, Left, Right } from 'native-base';

export default class WebViewScreen extends React.Component {
  

  buttonOnPress = () => {
    console.warn('button Pressed')
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.WEBVIEW_REF = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

<Icon style={styles.Icon} onPress={() => this.WEBVIEW_REF.current.goBack()}>
          <Text style={{textAlign: 'left', color: '#000000' }}></Text>
          <Icon name="arrow-back" />
        </Icon>
        
        <WebView
        
          source={{ uri: 'http://www.catalogmasr.com' }}
          style={styles.webview}
          ref={this.WEBVIEW_REF}
        />

        
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
  webview: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  icon: {
    padding : 2, 
    backgroundColor: '#cdcccc', 
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
```

Comment: if platform.os===web how to handle

Answer (score 1):

All of the times I needed to handle the Back button at a Webview (or component), I needed to tell the component that my function was the correct handler/listener to the event.

```
componentDidMount() {
    

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.buttonOnPress );
    } }

componentWillUnmount() {

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress');
    }  }
```

Best of luck, hope it fixes it for you.

Comment: if platform.os===web how to handle